# How to add Csfr token before each ajax call dynamically in CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp, csrf

I am working with CakePHP 3.6. I have a function that will return some data using AJAX call. This function will be called from any page of my website. It is like a button will be there and on clicking that button a modal will come with some data. Those data will come from AJAX call. So now the problem I am facing is with Csrf token. If I click from a page where a form is available then this AJAX call working perfect because there is a Csrf token available because of that form. But when I try clicking from a page where no form is available then AJAX is giving Csrf error. Because there is no Csrf added for that page.

This is how my button click and Ajax calling function looks like

```
$("#td-apt").on('click', function() {
    getModalData();
    $("#data-modal").modal('toggle');
});

function getModalData () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/function/Data",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success')
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

So here are the things is it possible to generate Csrf token every time before calling this AJAX url. Or any other way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the token from the request object in your view templates, for example in the layout to make it globally available:

```
<script>
var csrfToken = <?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')) ?>;
// ...
</script>
```

You can then easily use it in your AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    },
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, if you already have some JS cookie parser at hand, you can obtain it from the cookie named `csrfToken`.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Middleware >  Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware > CSRF Protection and AJAX Requests](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests)**